# Unable to enter Docker container on remote Linux box with procedure that works fine on local box?

Tags: linux, process, docker, pid, nsenter

I have nsenter set up on my local and remote Linux boxes.  The remote box is a hosted virtual machine.  The local box is a computer in my office.  Both are running Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS server version and both of them have the kernel patch to support docker.  My local box is running Docker 1.0.1, the apt-get version for Docker.  The remote box is running 1.4.1, the latest and greatest.

Here is the procedure I use to execute nsenter on both machines, shown with the remote machine details:

```
kelpmaster@external:~$ sudo docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} fluffy_cinnamon
32113
kelpmaster@external:~$ sudo nsenter --target 32113 --mount --ipc --net --pid
nsenter: cannot open /proc/32113/ns/pid: No such file or directory
```

I checked the process list on the remote box and *32113* is definitely in the process list.  I checked the file structure and there definitely is a directory *named /proc/32113/ns*.  However, on my remote box the file/directory named *pid* does *not exist* in the process namespace folder.  On my local box *it does.*

Why is the *pid* file/directory missing from my remote box when it is being created properly on my local box?  How can I fix this so I can *nsenter* my Docker container on the remote box like I can on my local box?

Comment: Not sure if nsenter still works with recent versions of docker. Since docker 1.3 (if memory serves me) you can use `docker exec` instead, see https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec

Comment: @user2915097 Just tried docker exec.  Getting a "broken pipe" error when I try it.  Did some Google searching and found a indicating there might be kernel incompatibilities with that.  Admittedly the message is in the context of Fedora: https://www.mail-archive.com/golang@lists.fedoraproject.org/msg05209.html

Answer (score 1):

Use lxc-checkconfig to see if 'pid namespace: enabled' or else its the kernel.

you can also look for 
Cgroup: enabled
Cgroup namespace: enabled

if not mount it appropriately.